# preventing recursive promises and associated inability to free mem

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-leaks, promise, bluebird

Consider concurrent workers that consume from a queue until the queue is empty.

Each concurrent worker calls `letWorkerDrainQueue` which processes a message if one is found on the queue. Afterwards, `letWorkerDrainQueue` recursively calls itself to process the next message and so on.

See concise code below.

```
//10 workers execute 'letWorkerDrainQueue' in parallel.
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    //irrelevant here: _.range(x) creates an array of 10 elements
    return Promise.map(_.range(10), () => letWorkerDrainQueue());
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DONE (queue empty. All workers have returned)");
  });

//each worker executes letWorkerDrainQueue.
//If a message is found -> it's processed + 'letWorkerDrainQueue' is called recursively to process next message
//if no message found -> letWorkerDrainQueue is done.
function letWorkerDrainQueue() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      return receiveMessage(); // Implementation is irrelevant for question
    })
    .then(msg => {
      if (!msg) return null; //no message on queue anymore -> let's quit this work
      return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
          return processMessage(msg); // Implementation is irrelevant for question
        })
        .then(() => {
          //recursion happens here
          return letWorkerDrainQueue();
        });
    }); //catch etc omitted for conciseness
}
```

Afaik, this results in an extremely deep nested promise-chain that can never be freed from memory. Consequently all variables 'locked up' in any of these promises (here `msg`) can not be freed from mem either.

This is a problem since this process will run out of memory given enough time.

How would I restructure this? There's a nagging feel I can restructure this tail-recursion with a loop but how to do this with the async nature of promises is beyond me. Anyone?

Comment: What has led you to believe this would lead to locked up memory? I would think that `mem` would be GCed as soon as there is nothing referring to it anymore (e.g. all functions referencing it have been called). Have you done any testing to see if this leads to runaway memory usage?

Comment: I'm seeing some leaks in my (albeit far more complex) code. It's hard to find out why so I'm looking at various things. Having said that, wouldn't it be logical the above leads to unrecoverable instances of both promises as well as contained `msg` inside the promise? I.e.: You get a callstack as follows -> `letWorkerDrainQueue(msg) -> letWorkerDrainQueue(msg) -> letWorkerDrainQueue(msg)`. None of the promises can complete until the last one completes it seems. Therefore all are referenced and non can be gc'ed? Perhaps I'm missing something?